# Size of the observable universe and CMBR

Tags: cosmology, cosmic-microwave-background, observable-universe

Why can we detect the Microwave Background radiation (the earliest light that we can see) and not the light from stars beyond the observable universe?   Should not the microwave radiation also be beyond what we can detect?

Comment: The observable universe is by definition the region of space up to which we can establish causal contact i.e. observe. How can you detect something beyond what is defined as the very delimitation of what is detectable?

Answer (score 3):

The source of the CMB filled all space. The light from the parts of all space that were closer to us (at the time the CMB was emitted) than the sources of the most distant light that we can see has already passed us. The part that was just far enough away from us that the light from it is just now reaching us is what is currently visible. We can see closer things if they emitted light later. We can't see farther things because light from them hasn't had long enough to get here.